# How can I change from using a static class to hold globals to using a Singleton pattern?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Right now my code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
namespace City
{
    public static class MS 
    {

        public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

        private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
                StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private static int timerSeconds;
        public static int TimerSeconds
        {
            get { return timerSeconds; }
            set { timerSeconds = value; NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("TimerSeconds"); }
        }
    }
}
```

and this XAML

```
 <Label x:Name="timer" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MS.TimerSeconds}}" />
        </Grid>
```

The code works but in a previous questions one of the posters said this:

> I would strongly recomend you to not use static class to keep data and
>   bind something to them. Stange things may happen - in your code you
>   are calling event with null sender. Event if it's working right now,
>   it may not work with future releases of Xamarin.Forms. At least use
>   singleton pattern - it allows you to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
>   interface

Can someone explain or show me a very short example of what is meant here. Should I for example create a class in the application start area and how could I change that to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do. Implement below and if you need a singleton (I am not sure why as I don't know your design) you access it as "MSSingleton.Instance" but I would try to avoid even singleton and just create MS object when you need it.

```
    public class MSSingleton : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //if you need singleton
        static MSSingleton _instance = null;
        public static MSSingleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new MSSingleton();
                return _instance;
            }

        }


        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private int timerSeconds;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int TimerSeconds
        {
            get { return timerSeconds; }
            set { timerSeconds = value; OnPropertyChanged("TimerSeconds"); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct implementation of singleton pattern. Correct implementations are described in Jon's Skeet [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: @Kedrzu - Can you give a very short example or mention what is wrong?

Comment: You can use it with lock if you expect that it will be used in multi threading environment or static constructor. You also can use Lazy loading if you wish. My answer implement the first version of the article which is not thread-safe and doesn't use lazy loading.  From my experience it is good enough for most requirements especially for Xamarin but feel free to make it more complicated :-) Read "Performance vs laziness" of the article and also decide if your class is used in multi threaded environment.

Comment: As Yuri wrote, this is not thread-safe version of singleton. I agree that generally it will work. Even xamarin may have multithreading issues and making it thread safe cost almost nothing. Following implementation is a little bit easier and thread safe: `public static MSSingleton Instance {get;} = new MSSingleton();`